# UITableView indexPath.row not increasing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am loading data into a UITableView.  The first load happens properly for the first 10 cells in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {}
```

the indexPath.row increments properly and loads the data into the proper cells from the data source.  I then implemented a load more when the bottom of the table is reached.  Now func tableView is called but it is stuck at indexPath.row = 9.  I have implemented a checker in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
```

And it appears that the proper number of rows has been added.

Edit:  I having issue with the my second uitableview (there are two in this scene)  The checker is a print statement that is called and returns the proper uitableView and this happens before the tableView gets stuck at the same value.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if tableView == self.table {
            return users2.count

        }
        else {
            print("married barry", tableFeedCount)
            return tableFeedCount
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does your 'checker' code look like ?

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

**Declare boolean**

```
let boolNotMoreData : Bool = true
```

**Append new data to your data source**

```
 let arrResponse: [Any]? = (responseObject["news"] as? [Any])
 if arrResponse?.count == 0{
                boolNotMoreData = false;
        }
    for dictResponse in arrResponse as! [[String: Any]] {
          self.arrDataSource.append(NewsClass(responseDict: dictResponse))
        }
        self.tblViewNews?.reloadData()
```

**Now fetch new data**

```
private func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == arrNews.count - 1 {
            if boolNotMoreData {
                currentPage += 1
                getYourData()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**This worked Successfully**

```
    @IBOutlet weak var Submitted: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ViewAssigenment: UITableView!
    var Arrayone:[String] = []
    var ArrayTwo:[String] = []

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
        {
            var count:Int?
            if tableView == self.ViewAssigenment
            {
                count = Arrayone.count
            }
            else if tableView == self.Submitted
            {
                count = ArrayTwo.count
            }
            return count!
        }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        if tableView == self.ViewAssigenment
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ViewCell") as!
            ViewAssigenmentTableViewCell
            let obj =Arrayone[indexPath.row]

           cell.lblTitle.text = obj.AssTitle



            return cell

        }
        else
        {
            let  cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Submittcell") as! SubmittedAssigenmentTableViewCell
            let obj2 = ArrayTwo[indexPath.row]

            cell1.lbltitle.text = obj2.AssTitle

            return cell1
        }

    }
```